# Android: AndroidManifest.xml with errors after doing checkout from respository

Tags: android

After doing the checkout of repository (Bitbucket) I can't run my project in Android Studio (version 2.3.3) because I have errors(in red) in AndroidManifest.xml as you can see in the screenshot below:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

[image: Androidmanifest.xml]

**strings.xml**

[image]

The errors are "Cannot resolve symbol @string/app_name" and "Unresolved class MainActivity". I've already do the Invalidate/Caches Restart but it didn't resolve it. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Its because you are having a red icons inside your package name "Interface".Try to clean and rebuild your project again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

try clean and rebuild the project again 
also check is gradle build succesfully ?